# Entity framework - selecting from child lists without getting top level object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In my model, a "User" has "Projects".

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

(amongst other things).

IN code, I'm wanting to get a list of projects:

```
var p = _context.User(x => x.Id == someUserId).Projects;
```

This is pulling the user object as well, but I don't want it to (its wasted effort).

I could change my project model to not have an object relationship with User but that breaks other things because the relationship is expected for other things.

What's the best way to achieve this?
On the Project class, can I have both UserId and a User object reference?

Comment: How about using a `.select` and selecting only  projects

Comment: "can I have both UserId and a User object reference" - sure. Moreover, this is a common practice.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx, it might give you some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about start your query by `Projects` instead of `Users`? I think you might have a Fk property in `Project` entity referring to the related `User`:

```
var projects=_context.Projects.Where(p=>p.UserId==someUserId);
```

So, your `Project` entity should have these two properties

```
public class Project
{
   //other properties


   //FYI, EF by a name convention will use this property as FK,
   //but is a good practice specify explicitly which is the FK in a relationship 
   [ForeignKey("User")]
   public int UserId{get;set;}

   public virtual User User{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yep so that basically answers my question about having them both, which indeed does solve it. Hopefully this won't screw with code first and table creation.